# How change SDP(string) file content?

Tags: javascript, sdp

If I have SDP file and want to change content of it:

```
    v=0
    o=jdoe 2890844526 2890842807 IN IP4 10.47.16.5
    s=SDP Seminar
    i=A Seminar on the session description protocol
    u=http://www.example.com/seminars/sdp.pdf
    e=j.doe@example.com (Jane Doe)
    c=IN IP4 224.2.17.12/127
    t=2873397496 2873404696
    a=recvonly
    m=audio 49170 RTP/AVP 0
    m=video 51372 RTP/AVP 99
    a=rtpmap:99 h263-1998/90000
```

How can I change content in each line for example I can change **49170** (content of 'm') in that line.

Comment: Please be more specific: what programming language are you using and what platform (my guess is you're trying to use JS in node.js, but I cannot be sure). Can you give an example of the transformed file?

Comment: Yes exactly I use javascript and node.js in VS,I tagged in bellow the program

Answer (score 0):

```
 function change_Ip_Port(new_sdp_file){
    let lines = new_sdp_file.split('\n').map(l => l.trim());
    lines.forEach(function(line) {
        if (line.indexOf('m=video') === 0) {
          console.log(line);
        }
        else if (line.indexOf('m=audio') === 0) {
          console.log(line);
        }
        if(line.indexOf('c=IN')===0) {
          console.log(line);
        }
    });
  }
```

Comment: The problem is this, I need to change in each line that I could extract change port like I add in bellow of question ...I still miss that part!

Comment: If I were you I'd move the code in the answer in the original question and then I'd delete this answer.

Comment: May I suggest you use a regex to find and replace the interesting values? I believe you can easily find a regex tutorial, for example there is one at https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp

Comment: I trying to use"replaceAt" but doesn't give me answer @Dan

Comment: Please help me to solve my problem :( @Dan I add my new code that implemented

Answer (score 0):

```
    let lines = new_sdp_file.split('\n').map(l => l.trim());
    lines.forEach(function(line) {
      if (line.indexOf('m=video') === 0) {
        setDefaultCodec(line, ServicesPort);
        }
      else if (line.indexOf('m=audio') === 0) {
          console.log(line);
        }
        if(line.indexOf('c=IN')===0) {
        }
    });
  }
  function setDefaultCodec(mLine, payloud) {
    var elements = mLine.split(' ');
    for (var i = 1; i < elements.length; i++) {
      if (elements[1] !== payloud) {
      //In here I should add replace inestead of 49170 for example R = 1180
        console.log(mLine);
      }
    }
    return elements.join(' ');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are a code sequence that will help you parse the line starting with "m=audio" and then generate the new line. You have to integrate it yourself in your code and then write back the updated line to the file.
You have to write yourself the code to process the other lines.

```
var regex = new RegExp( "^m=audio(\\s+)(\\d+)(\\s+)([A-Z]+/[A-Z]+)(\\s+)(\\d+)$" );
var line = "m=audio 49170 RTP/AVP 0";
var match = regex.exec( line );
// You should replace the field0, field1 and field2 names with
// actual names for the fields in the file.
var field0 = match[ 2 ];
var field1 = match[ 4 ];
var field2 = match[ 6 ];
var field0NewValue = 40000;
var newLine = "m=audio " + field0NewValue + " " + field1 + " " + field2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've taken your answer, and added to it. This was a useful question, and this is my take on it:

```
function setBandwidth(sdp) {
    let lines = sdp.split('\r\n').map(l => l.trim());
    let returnSdp = '';
    let audioBandwidth = '64';
    let videoBandwidth = '1280';
    lines.forEach(function(line, index) {
        if (line.indexOf('m=audio') === 0) {
            lines[index] = line + '\r\nb=AS:' + audioBandwidth;
        }
        if (line.indexOf('m=video') === 0) {
            lines[index] = line + '\r\nb=AS:' + videoBandwidth;
        }
        returnSdp = returnSdp + lines[index];
        if (index < lines.length - 1) {
            returnSdp = returnSdp + '\r\n';
        }
    });
    return returnSdp;
}
```

For me, finding the line, then adding to it to the next line was easiest, since the b:as lines weren't there in the first place, and those are the lines that I'm trying to add.

Also, note that there shouldn't be an extra newline at the end of the sip lines, hence I put code to not have that happen.